# Is there Text Selection Listener in WebView

Tags: android, webview, listener

Does Android provides text selection listener in WebView? For example, user select text in web view. Selected text will be shown in toast.
If there is no such listener, how to implement this idea in other ways?

PS. Please note that I do not mean copying or some action modes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, `WebView` handles text selection internally and does not provide any listeners regarding this.

The selection is updated when user moves the cursor on the web page. One possible way to achieve your goal, is to call `WebViewClassic.getSelection()` whenever user moves the cursor during text selection. Since this is not a public API, you may need to utilize **Java Reflection**.

So you may also need to override `onTouchEvent()`, in your App to decide whether user has entered selection mode and especially when s/he moves the cursor. If yes,  calling `WebViewClassic.getSelection()` will result in a string of what has been selected.

Comment: How can i access getSelection() from my webview object ? Please help me.

Comment: @Anilkumar As said you may need to utilize **Java Reflection**. But please also note that `WebViewClassic` is a concept of Android WebKit, which has been removed since Android KitKat, replaced by Chromium WebKit.